# Object doesn't display correctly after compilation with PS2EXE

Tags: winforms, powershell, object

I created a PowerShell program with a graphical interface. When I execute it directly in PowerShell everything is functional.

I then decided to compile my program *.PS1* to *.EXE* with the script `PS2EXE` and with the option `NoConsole` which allows to hide the black PowerShell  window which runs in background task.

However, variables object which I use don't display anymore correctly! I tried with and without the PowerShell console in background task, and I noticed that it was bound to that.

Here is how I show the values of my variable object:

```
$Output = $Output | Format-Table | Out-String
$TextBox2.Text = $Output
```

My object contains various properties as `Program` or `ComputerName`.

Indeed, I wanted that in my TextBox, the values display as in the PowerShell console.

What other method could I use so that my values display correctly without the console in background task? A `ForEach` loop?